# How to implement hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) for a struct

Tags: swift, struct, protocols, hashable

I have a `struct`, Student that conforms to `Hashable` protocol but I am getting an error for the `hash(into:)` method.

```
struct Student: Hashable{
    let studentID: Int
    let name: String

    init(studentID id:Int, andName name: String){
        studentID = id
        self.name = name
    }
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher){
        hasher.combine(bytes: ObjectIdentifier(self.Type)) //giving compile-time error
    }
    static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool{
        return (lhs == rhs)
    }
}
```

I am getting error for the function `hash(into:)`. As Student is a struct not class, I am confused on how to implement the required `hash(into:)` function. Can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 3):

Here it is for your case

```
func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher){
    hasher.combine(studentID)
    hasher.combine(name)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked. However from my code, it was not clear that the studentID is unique, so I just need to combine studentID.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest form is

```
struct Student: Hashable {
    let studentID: Int
    let name: String
}
```

You get the initializer, `Equatable` (the `==` operator) and `hash(into)` for free. The hasher considers all struct members.

If you want only `studentID` to be considered write

```
struct Student: Hashable {
    let studentID: Int
    let name: String

    static func == (lhs: Student, rhs: Student) -> Bool {
        return lhs.studentID == rhs.studentID
    }

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(studentID)
    }
}
```

Comment: In your second solution you must also override `==`.

Comment: Only considering `studentID` here would violate Equatable: "Equality implies substitutability—any two instances that compare equally can be used interchangeably in any code that depends on their values. To maintain substitutability, the == operator should take into account all visible aspects of an Equatable type." I don't believe Identifiable gives you Equatable (and shouldn't, since it only tests `id`).

Comment: @RobNapier `Identifiable` conforms to `Equatable` and synthesizes `==` based on `id`.

Comment: @vadian Can you double-check that? I don't see Identifiable requiring Equatable in the stdlib, or in my playground experiments. `struct X: Identifiable { var id: Int }; X(id: 1) == X(id: 2)` returns the error I expect: `Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two 'X' operands`. Is there an extension in SwiftUI or something I'm missing?

Comment: @RobNapier My bad, I was under the impression that `Identifiable` adds `Equatable` implicitly, because the required `id` property must be `Hashable`, sorry.